# SQL subtotals, problems with grouping

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would appreciate some direction on SQL subtotals.  Am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Tables used:

```
OrderInvoiceHeader.ProvinceCode
OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceNumber
OrderInvoiceHeader.BillToCustomer
OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceDate
OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceAmount
OrderInvoiceHeader.GstAmount
OrderInvoiceHeader.PstAmount

Customer.BillToCustomer
Customer.CustomerName

CanadaProvinces.ProvinceCode
CanadaProvinces.ProvinceName
```

I must show on query:
Each InvoiceNumber, ProvinceName, CustomerName, InvoiceDate, InvoiceAmount, GstAmount, and PstAmount must be shown.
Must have subtotals by ProvinceName to include sums of InvoiceAmount, GstAmount, and PstAmount.
Must have subtotal for all provinces to include sums of InvoiceAmount, GstAmount, and PstAmount.

Sequence must be ProvinceName, CustomerName, InvoiceNumber.

Comment: usually subtotals and grouping is handled outside SQL within the reporting layer.  just make sure you have a proper order by, so the rows are in order for the groups

Comment: read about GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ()

Comment: The part I do not really understand is that I must include InvoiceDate in Select (as an example), thus am forced to include in Group By, which then gives extra row subtotals (by InvoiceDate) when with rollup is used.  Same would be true for CustomerName.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said - grouping sets:

```
select 
    InvoiceNumber   = case grouping(InvoiceNumber) when 1 then '<Total>' else InvoiceNumber end, 
    ProvinceName    = case grouping(ProvinceName) when 1 then '<Total>' else ProvinceName end, 
    CustomerName    = case grouping(CustomerName) when 1 then '<Total>' else CustomerName end, 
    InvoiceDate = case grouping(InvoiceDate) when 1 then '<Total>' else InvoiceDate, end  
    sum(InvoiceAmount), sum(GstAmount), sum(PstAmount)
from [table]
group by 
    grouping sets (
        (ProvinceName, InvoiceNumber, CustomerName, InvoiceDate),
        (ProvinceName),
        ()  -- grand total
    )
```

You could achieve this with `rollup` or `cube`, but you'd have to use grouping([column]) to filter out unneeded aggregations.

Comment: @JamesHinson. You wouldn't mind accepting the answert then, would you? :)